# Get property from checkbox in gridpane

Tags: java, javafx

this is part of homework.

How do I access a property of checkboxes that are placed inside a gridpane? If I do it via:

`.getChildren()`

It returns a list of nodes, which I can access with

`.get(i)`

Which then naturally returns an object of type Node, however through this I can't access the properties of the checkbox, only those which a node would have. I've tried finding a solution by reading documentations and googling around, but can't seem to find a solution to this.

The Gridpane is filled with checkboxes, so there's no need to check if a node is a checkbox, and I need to check the selected property of each box.

I would love a pointer in the right direction.

Comment: Another option, other than casting, is to keep direct references to the each `CheckBox` (e.g. in a field). If there are too many `CheckBox` objects to maintain in distinct fields then you can store them in their own `List<CheckBox>` or some other collection.

Comment: Slaw's suggestion would be my preferred approach: The order of the children in a `GridPane` may or may not correspond to their position in the `GridPane` and retrieving the position of a child is unnecessary, if you could just use a nested `CheckBox[][]` array or something similar. Furthermore this won't break, if you decide to add more elements to the `GridPane` at some time in the future...

Comment: I will keep this suggestion in mind, but more as a reminder that I have to get better in programming overall. I understand what you guys are saying, but I have never applied it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the `Node`, cast it to `CheckBox` then call `isSelected()` or other methods.

Maybe something like this?

```
for (Node node : gridplane.getChildren()) {
    if (node instanceof CheckBox) {
        CheckBox ckbox = (CheckBox)node;
        // do stuff with ckbox.
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes! That works. I had an idea that casting might work, but I'm not very familiar with doing this. I should read up on it more. Thank you.